# Perda de Encode ao minimizar javascript no Grails

Tags: utf-8, grails, encode

No meu arquivo javascript existe uma mensagem com a string "serviço" por exemplo.
Quando eu rodo o projeto (run-app) e verifico o javascript pelo navegador, a palavra aparece como: "serviÃ§o". Mas esta é exibida corretamente na tela quando a mensagem é invocada.

Porém quando eu executo o sistema através de um pacote gerado (package), e verifico o javascript pelo navegador, aparece a palavra como: "servi\u00c3\u00a7o". Quando a mensagem aparece na tela, é exibido: "serviÃ§o"

Encontrei uma pessoa com o problema idêntico ao meu, nesse link:
https://github.com/bertramdev/grails-asset-pipeline/issues/322

Porém a solução de utilizar "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" não funcionou para mim.

Tentei com os comandos abaixo e nada:

grails -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 package

gradle -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 assetCompile

Answer (score 0):

Victor isso já aconteceu comigo, é o seguinte o encoding da response da sua requisição está está diferente de UTF-8, sendo esse o motivo desse transtorno, o que você pode fazer é seta isso manualmente dentro da action do seu controller, ou você pode criar um interceptor do Grails e setar o enconding em todas as suas requisições, eu fiz isso na minha aplicação e funciona perfeitamente, segue o código do interceptor.

```
class EncodingInterceptor {

    public EncodingInterceptor(){
        match controller: '*'
    }

    boolean before() {
        response.characterEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
}
```

Comment: Não faz muito sentido no meu caso, pois o erro de encoding é no javascript e não no retorno das requisições.

Comment: Cara da uma olhada no enconding da response, e vê se não é isso, se não for isso, provençalmente é o enconding do arquivo, tem como você definir ela na sua IDE.

Comment: Não amigo, não tem nenhuma relação com response e não tem problema nenhum no encoding do arquivo. Conforme descrevi na dúvida, o sistema funciona normalmente, o problema ocorre somente quando o pacote é gerado (pois o javascript é minimizado em um arquivo só)

Comment: Hm..., você verificou o encoding da response desse arquivo js?

Comment: sim está UTF-8 como o restante dos arquivos.